# Analytics tag not persisting between sessions

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, tracking

I'm using Sitecore 9.0.2 and I'm attempting to use tags in Sitecore analytics to track if a particular modal has been closed, so it doesn't reappear. This is working within a session, but when the browser is closed and reopened, the modal reappears. I did confirm via Fiddler that the `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` value is the same in both sessions.

I created an extension to take my tag ID and set a value of "1" to it (I mainly care if the tag exists). This is my set code:

```
    public static void SetTag(this string tagId, string value) {
        Contact contact = Tracker.Current?.Contact;

        if (contact == null) {
            Logger.Info("SetTag: Contact not found");
            return;
        }

        ITag tag = contact.Tags.Find(tagId);

        if (tag == null) {
            contact.Tags.Set(tagId, value);
        }
    }
```

I noticed that anonymous contacts don't show in Experience Profile, which I remember they changed by default in 8.2.3. I'm not sure if that's related and I just need to turn the anonymous tracker on or if using tags for this purpose isn't best practice because they don't persist session to session (at least for anonymous users).